# How to compare two collections values in oracle?

Tags: oracle, collections, user-defined-types

Suppose in one collection(Nested Collection) a I have values (1,2,3,4,5) and in another collection b I have values (5,6,7,8,9). In both collection 5 is common . How to compare and return 5?

Comment: Where do you "have" the collections? Are you in a SQL context, or in PL/SQL? Also, "collection" is a generic name; your collections don't look like associative arrays, but they could be varrays or nested tables. So, what kind of collections are they?

Comment: Nested collection

Comment: @APC - what is a "Nested Collection"? I assumed the OP meant "nested table", but I see you used the same term, "nested collection", which I haven't heard before.

Comment: @mathguy - I didn't do that edit (I just edited the tags): the term is solely the OP's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a collection you can use the `MULTISET INTERSECT` operator:

```sql
CREATE TYPE intlist IS TABLE OF int;

DECLARE
  a intlist := intlist(1,2,3,4,5);
  b intlist := intlist(5,6,7,8,9);
  c intlist;
BEGIN
  c := a MULTISET INTERSECT b;

  FOR i in 1 .. c.COUNT LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT( c(i) || ',' );
  END LOOP;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.NEW_LINE();
END;
/
```

outputs:

```
5,
```

> I need to compare each value using loop.

Loop through one array and use the `MEMBER OF` operator to check whether each element is in another array:

```sql
DECLARE
  a intlist := intlist(1,2,3,4,5);
  b intlist := intlist(5,6,7,8,9);
  c intlist;
BEGIN
  c := intlist();
  FOR i IN 1 .. a.COUNT LOOP
    IF a(i) MEMBER OF b THEN
      c.EXTEND;
      c(c.COUNT) := a(i);
    END IF;
  END LOOP;

  FOR i IN 1 .. c.COUNT LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT( c(i) || ',' );
  END LOOP;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.NEW_LINE();
END;
/
```

also outputs:

```
5,
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=96851dfb7c35e6bd5676f62989eecaa8)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean by "Collection" a [Nested Table](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/composites.htm#GUID-5ADB7EE2-71F6-4172-ACD8-FFDCF2787A37) you can simply use

```
TYPE NumberArray IS TABLE OF INTEGER;    
ret := NumberArray(1,2,3,4,5) MULTISET INTERSECT NumberArray(5,6,7,8,9);
```

Check also some other [Multiset Operators](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/operators006.htm#SQLRF0032) and [Multiset Conditions](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/conditions006.htm#SQLRF52128)

If you just need "compare", i.e. "equal or not" then you can simply use

```
IF NumberArray(1,2,3,4,5) = NumberArray(5,6,7,8,9) THEN ...
```

Comment: Thanks but I need to compare each value using loop.

Comment: @iteng  -  why "using loop"?  Surely that can't be part of the problem statement (unless it's homework, which you didn't tell us); what to **use** is part of the solution, not part of the problem. SQL and PL/SQL have built-in operators for this (`INTERSECT`, or perhaps `MULTISET INTERSECT`) - those hide the loops from you. So, again: **why "using loop"**?

Comment: If you will not use loop then how you will compare each values?

Comment: @iteng - what do you mean by "compare each values"? In your original post, you show two nested tables, and you want all the common elements. If you were to do this by hand, you would compare each element from the first collection to each element from the second collection (in a loop - actually in two loops, one nested within the other). In Oracle SQL and PL/SQL, you don't need to do that **yourself**; the software does exactly that for you, when you use the `INTERSECT` operator, as Wernfried has already shown. Why do **you** have to do the comparison, when Oracle does it for you?

Comment: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=63585221592e824de4f8b191647617d9) `PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "INTERSECT" when expecting one of the following:

   . ( * % & = - + ; < / > at in is mod remainder not rem
   <an exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like like2
   like4 likec between || multiset member submultiset`

Comment: Word of warning... Using a loop might make sense, if the ordering is important... Oracle handles NumberArray(1,2,3)=NumberArray(3,2,1) as true, since ordering of the numbers is not important (probably since it uses a collection operation internally)...